# How to sort a view based table column

Tags: cocoa

I have a view based NSOutlineView, and in one column there is my custom NSTableCellView (contain NSImageView and NSTextField)

```
- (NSView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(CustomItem*)item
{
    CustomTableCellView *cellView [outlineView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self]; 
    cellView.textField.stringValue = item.name;
    return cellView;
}
```

Right now, i want to sort this column by the property of CustomItem (`name`), from the screenshot, what should i do the set the sort descriptor?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself, i can use a NSOutelineViewDataSource method to monitor the change of the sort descriptor.

```
- (void)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView sortDescriptorsDidChange:(NSArray<NSSortDescriptor *> *)oldDescriptors
{

}
```